# converting String to string array

Tags: java

I have a string category = "1-4-5-10-13-27-28-29-32-34-35-36-51-58-150" and I want to convert it into string array

I already tried this code :

```
List<String> oldCat = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(category.split(",")));
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: What do you think `split(",")` does? Also `List<String>` is not string array. Post example of expected result.

Comment: How does any part of that code help accomplish your goal?

Comment: I'm sorry. I already got this. inside my split it should not be like this (",") but rather this ("-"). Im sorry guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
String category = "1-4-5-10-13-27-28-29-32-34-35-36-51-58-150";
String [] categoryArray = category.split("-");
```

Then if you want to end up with an `ArrayList<String>` do:

```
List<String> categoryArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
Collections.addAll(categoryArrayList, categoryArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to split the string into a string. Try this

```
String[] ary = category.split("-");
```

This will return an array